# inserting image base on description

Tags: php

I wanted to insert image into my database , after I send in the forms.

it will be display based on the description instead of id.
I'm following one tutorial which was showing how to insert based on id,
which is the following code 
//Add this prouct into the database now

```
$sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO supermarket (category,subcategory,name,description,packaging,price)
VALUES ('$category','$subcategory','$product_name','$product_description','$product_package','$product_price')");




$pid= mysql_insert_id();
//place image in the folder
$newname = "$pid.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'],"images/$newname");
    header("location: inventory_list.php"); 
    exit();
}
```

now,
i would like to change it to based on description.
I not whether did I do it correctly.

```
   $pdes = mysql_insert_description();
    //place image in the folder
    $newname = "$pdes.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'],"images/$newname");
        header("location: inventory_list.php"); 
        exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `mysql_insert_description()` method. You don't need a `mysql` method here though, you already have the `$product_description` variable available to you.

It looks like you should be able to simply do this:

```
$newname = "$product_description.jpg";
```

Comment: can I write
$sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO supermarket (category,subcategory,name,description,packaging,image,price)
VALUES ('$category','$subcategory','$product_name','$product_description','$product_package',$product_image','$product_price')");
   
in my sql so that it will be inserted into my databse

Comment: @user3198445 Isn't that what you already have? Haven't you tested your already existing code to see if it works?

Comment: @Wipqozn I just added that new code because I want in to store in db. I tried the previous code, it doesn't store it in my db

Comment: @user3198445 I really have no idea where your information is coming from, where the variables are getting set, you don't show a lot of code. But once you get your query working and inserting `$product_description` into the database, you can then just use that same variable for your image name.

Comment: @user3198445 what doesn't work? the insert query? what's the query error (if it doesn't work, there's always an error)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163211/how-to-insert-image-into-database-based-on-upload-forms/21163458?noredirect=1#21163458
take a look