# how to insert image into database based on upload forms

Tags: php

I would like to insert image into the database, based on doing a upload form.

My query works, able to insert all the field except image when I submit the form
However, When I changed my code to add image into database,
the code doesn't work anymore, it doesn't insert my field into the database.

Can someone tell me what can I do in order to insert my image into database after clicking on submit button?

```
  <?php
if(isset($_POST['description'])){
    $product_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_name']);
    $product_price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_price']);
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
    $subcategory = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subcategory']);
    $product_description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
    $product_package = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_package']);
    $product_image = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_image']);




$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM supermarket WHERE description='$product_description' LIMIT 1");
$productMatch = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($productMatch > 0) {
    echo "Sorry you tried to place a duplicate 'Product Description' into the system, <a href='invertorylist.php'>click here</a>";
    exit();
}

//add name of image hear
$newname = "$product_description.jpg";

//Add this prouct into the database now
$sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO supermarket (category,subcategory,name,description,image,packaging,price)
VALUES ('$category','$subcategory','$product_name','$product_description',$product_image','$product_package','$product_price')");




//place image in the folder
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'],"images/$newname");
    header("location: inventorylist.php"); 
    exit();

}
```

Comment: Why don't you save the image, and insert the filepath into database?

Comment: what do you mean? because right from the start, I have image in my database.. && I'm displaying all the image, based on the description itself.

Comment: I meant mysql database

Comment: you can "stringify" your image file using `base64encode()` in order to save it into database as `TEXT`, or you can store it binary but it is more advanced - both of these are not really recommend

Comment: is there a better way for me to put in database?

Comment: I recommend save it on server and save the file path (eg: "images/$newname") in mysql database

Answer (score 0):

```
//add name of image hear
$newname = "$product_description.jpg";

//Add this prouct into the database now 

$sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO supermarket (category,subcategory,name,description,image,packaging,price) VALUES ('$category','$subcategory','$product_name','$product_description','$newname','$product_package','$product_price')");


  //place image in the folder

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'],"images/$newname");
    header("location: inventorylist.php"); 
    exit(); }
```